# Spring MVC and jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: java, jquery, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am using Autocomplete Jquery in my project, but I can't get the suggestions.
When I try to write something in my text field, nothing is happen !!.

Here's the code:

**fournisseur.jsp**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="w-input-search" value="">
    <span><button id="button-id" type="button">Search</button></span>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#w-input-search').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/gestionFournisseur/getFournisseur.do',
        paramName: "fournisseurName",
        delimiter: ",",
       transformResult: function(response) {

        return {        
          //must convert json to javascript object before process
          suggestions: $.map($.parseJSON(response), function(item) {

              return { value: item.referenceFournisseur, data: item.idFournisseur };
           })

         };

            }

     });

  });
</script>
```

**My controller:**

```
package com.agro.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.agro.model.Fonction;
import com.agro.model.Fournisseur;
import com.agro.model.Pays;
import com.agro.model.PersonneContacter;
import com.agro.service.FonctionService;
import com.agro.service.FournisseurService;
import com.agro.service.PaysService;
import com.agro.service.PersonneContacterService;



@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/gestionFournisseur")
public class FournisseurController {
    public List<Fournisseur> listeFournisseur;

    @Autowired
    PaysService paysService;

    @Autowired
    FournisseurService fournisseurService;

    @Autowired
    FonctionService fonctionService;

    @Autowired
    PersonneContacterService personneContacterService;



    @RequestMapping(value="/listeFournisseur")
    public String index(ModelMap model){

        listeFournisseur= fournisseurService.getAllFournisseur();
        List<Pays> listePays = paysService.getAllPays();
        List<Fonction> listeFonction = fonctionService.getAllFonction();

        model.addAttribute("listeFourn", listeFournisseur);
        model.addAttribute("listePays", listePays);
        model.addAttribute("listeFonc", listeFonction);
        return "fournisseur";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addFournisseur", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String addFournisseur(String referenceFournisseur,String raisonSocial,String adresse,String adresse2,String tel, String tel2,String fax, String mail,String  idPays,
            String nomContact,String prenomContact,String telContact, String mailContact, String remarqueContact, String idFonction ){  

        Pays py = paysService.getPaysById(Integer.parseInt(idPays));
        Fonction fctn = fonctionService.getFonctionById(Integer.parseInt(idFonction));

        Fournisseur fourn = new Fournisseur(py, referenceFournisseur, raisonSocial, adresse, adresse2, tel, tel2, fax, mail);
        PersonneContacter prsnContact = new PersonneContacter(fctn, fourn, nomContact, prenomContact, telContact, mailContact, remarqueContact);

        fournisseurService.addFournisseur(fourn);
        personneContacterService.addPersonneContacter(prsnContact);

        return "ok";
    }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/getFournisseur", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody List<Fournisseur> getFournisseur(@RequestParam String fournisseurName){
            System.out.println("je suis dans getFournisseur");
            List<Fournisseur> result = new ArrayList<Fournisseur>();

            for(Fournisseur fourni : listeFournisseur){
                if(fourni.getReferenceFournisseur().contains(fournisseurName)){
                    result.add(fourni);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

}
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Agro</groupId>
    <artifactId>Agro</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
    </properties> 


    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
   </dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
 <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
 </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Base de donnee -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- need this for @Configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please, could someone tell how exactly it works ? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is with your client side code, check the browser console for any errors. Check if the autocomplete js is loading fine.

Comment: @underdog I got this message:           Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function$.widget._search @ jquery-ui.js:7399(anonymous function) @ jquery-ui.js:415$.widget.search @ jquery-ui.js:7391(anonymous function) @ jquery-ui.js:415(anonymous function) @ jquery-ui.js:7372handlerProxy @ jquery-ui.js:760

Comment: @underdog have you talked about this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}/gestionFournisseur/getFournisseur.do
```

You don't have any handler mapping for `getFournisseur.do` but `getFournisseur`. Get rid of that **.do** and it should work.